# SQL Server : mark the biggest percentage value in a table

Tags: sql, max, percentage, northwind

I have a little doubt, I'm doing some exercises with the `Northwind` database. I am trying to get a report that shows the shipments by year, with the total number of shipments of each shipping company. It also needs to show the percentage of shipments done by that company, and then needs to show which company did the most shipments (with an "X" for the company that did most shipments and with a "-" for the rest), like the commented part of the code:

```
IF (Perc > 36, "X", "-")
```

I already have part of the code, I'm only struggling with the last part.

Here is what I have:

```
SELECT 
    /* First we get the years. */
    DISTINCT YEAR(P.OrderDate) AS 'ShipYear',

    /* Now we get the names of the different shipping agencies. */
    (SELECT Shippers.CompanyName
     FROM dbo.Shippers
     WHERE Shippers.ShipperID = P.ShipVia) AS 'Shipper',

    /* The next step is counting the total of shipments *
     *  of that year with that company.                 */
    (SELECT COUNT(C.ShipVia)
     FROM dbo.Orders AS C
     WHERE YEAR(C.OrderDate) = YEAR(P.OrderDate)
       AND C.ShipVia = P.ShipVia) AS 'Shipments',

    /* Now we get it's percentage. */
    (SELECT (COUNT(C.ShipVia) * 100 / 
                        (SELECT COUNT(*)
                         FROM dbo.Orders AS CC
                         WHERE YEAR(CC.OrderDate) = YEAR(P.OrderDate)))
     FROM dbo.Orders AS C
     WHERE YEAR(C.OrderDate) = YEAR(P.OrderDate)
       AND C.ShipVia = P.ShipVia) AS 'Perc'

    --IF (Perc > 36, "X", "-")
FROM 
    [dbo].[Orders] AS P
WHERE 
    P.OrderDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(P.OrderDate)
GO
```

And here is a screenshot of the report:

[image: Table report]

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for windowing functions, using the [`OVER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql) clause.

You didn't specify which database you're using, so I linked to Microsoft SQL Server above.

Since `Perc` column is a sub-query, you should wrap your `SELECT` statement with another like this:

```
SELECT 'ShipYear', 'Shipper', 'Shipments', 'Perc'
     , MAX('Perc') OVER (PARTITION BY 'ShipYear') AS `MaxPerc`
  FROM ( // your query goes here
       ) x
```

That will show you how it works. Since you want `X` or `-`, you do this instead:

```
SELECT 'ShipYear', 'Shipper', 'Shipments', 'Perc'
     , CASE WHEN 'Perc' = MAX('Perc') OVER (PARTITION BY 'ShipYear')
            THEN 'X'
            ELSE '-'
       END AS 'Best'
  FROM ( // your query goes here
       ) x
```